# Is there an up to date fork of otx?

Tags: osx

otx is a tool used to disassemble Mach-O binaries on OS X 10.0-10.4.  It is an enhancement on top of otool to add additional symbol information to its disassembled output.

The main site and SVN repository (http://otx.osxninja.com/) appears to be long dead.  I've seen a few repos on GitHub but has anyone maintained or updated otx to work on modern versions of Mac OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most up to date fork I have found of `otx` is [Cai's](https://github.com/x43x61x69/otx). I have tried the CLI interface of his [v1.7: Build 566](https://github.com/x43x61x69/otx/releases/download/v1.7/otx_b566.zip) release on macOS 10.11.6 and it runs fine for basic disassembly, albeit on invoking it using `-o` to 'check the executable for obfuscation' against a little test code I wrote, it terminates with a

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[X8664Processor
>   verifyNops:numFound:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7fb7e5806200'

In my opinion there are better suited tools available today to disassemble binaries on OSX, among which even `otool` nowadays does not seem like it lacks functionality compared to `otx` for ad-hoc disassembly.

Let's have a quick look by disassembling the section of a [code](https://gist.github.com/moreaki/8b446ca85aecb93e2059c16d3c7cf9d6) which reads (essentially the 32bit version of `32-__builtin_clz(n)`):

```
static uint8_t f1_u32(uint32_t n) {
    return n ? 1 + f1_u32(n/2) : 0;
}
```

Using `otool -t -d -vV -j -q -H -P ./kk 2>/dev/null | grep -A24 "^_f1_u32:"` we get:

```
_f1_u32:
0000000100000de0    55  pushq   %rbp
0000000100000de1    48 89 e5    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000100000de4    48 83 ec 10     subq    $0x10, %rsp
0000000100000de8    89 7d fc    movl    %edi, -0x4(%rbp)
0000000100000deb    83 7d fc 00     cmpl    $0x0, -0x4(%rbp)
0000000100000def    0f 84 1b 00 00 00   je  0x100000e10
0000000100000df5    8b 45 fc    movl    -0x4(%rbp), %eax
0000000100000df8    c1 e8 01    shrl    $0x1, %eax
0000000100000dfb    89 c7   movl    %eax, %edi
0000000100000dfd    e8 de ff ff ff  callq   _f1_u32
0000000100000e02    0f b6 f8    movzbl  %al, %edi
0000000100000e05    83 c7 01    addl    $0x1, %edi
0000000100000e08    89 7d f8    movl    %edi, -0x8(%rbp)
0000000100000e0b    e9 0a 00 00 00  jmp 0x100000e1a
0000000100000e10    31 c0   xorl    %eax, %eax
0000000100000e12    89 45 f8    movl    %eax, -0x8(%rbp)
0000000100000e15    e9 00 00 00 00  jmp 0x100000e1a
0000000100000e1a    8b 45 f8    movl    -0x8(%rbp), %eax
0000000100000e1d    88 c1   movb    %al, %cl
0000000100000e1f    0f b6 c1    movzbl  %cl, %eax
0000000100000e22    48 83 c4 10     addq    $0x10, %rsp
0000000100000e26    5d  popq    %rbp
0000000100000e27    c3  retq
0000000100000e28    0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00     nopl    (%rax,%rax)
```

Using `./otx -d ./kk 2>/dev/null | grep -A26 "^_f1_u32:"`, this is the result:

```
_f1_u32:
    +0  0000000100000de0  55                 pushq    %rbp
    +1  0000000100000de1  4889e5             movq     %rsp,         %rbp
    +4  0000000100000de4  4883ec10           subq     $0x10,        %rsp
    +8  0000000100000de8  897dfc             movl     %edi,         -0x4(%rbp)
   +11  0000000100000deb  837dfc00           cmpl     $0x0,         -0x4(%rbp)
   +15  0000000100000def  0f841b000000       je       0x100000e10
   +21  0000000100000df5  8b45fc             movl     -0x4(%rbp),   %eax
   +24  0000000100000df8  c1e801             shrl     $0x1,         %eax
   +27  0000000100000dfb  89c7               movl     %eax,         %edi
   +29  0000000100000dfd  e8deffffff         callq    _f1_u32
   +34  0000000100000e02  0fb6f8             movzbl   %al,          %edi
   +37  0000000100000e05  83c701             addl     $0x1,         %edi
   +40  0000000100000e08  897df8             movl     %edi,         -0x8(%rbp)
   +43  0000000100000e0b  e90a000000         jmp      0x100000e1a   Anon4
   +48  0000000100000e10  31c0               xorl     %eax,         %eax
   +50  0000000100000e12  8945f8             movl     %eax,         -0x8(%rbp)
   +53  0000000100000e15  e900000000         jmp      0x100000e1a   Anon4

Anon4:
    +0  0000000100000e1a  8b45f8             movl     -0x8(%rbp),   %eax
    +3  0000000100000e1d  88c1               movb     %al,          %cl
    +5  0000000100000e1f  0fb6c1             movzbl   %cl,          %eax
    +8  0000000100000e22  4883c410           addq     $0x10,        %rsp
   +12  0000000100000e26  5d                 popq     %rbp
   +13  0000000100000e27  c3                 retq
   +14  0000000100000e28  0f1f840000000000   nopl     (%rax,%rax)
```

Besides cosmetic differences, we actually get (and expect) very similar output.

Unbeknownst of your agenda, in recent times I have found myself using [radare2](https://github.com/radare/radare2) or the [hopper](https://www.hopperapp.com/) GUI tool rather than fiddling with `otool` or `otx` when it comes to disassembly.

In hopper, you even get a decent pseudo code out of the disassembly (could be even better if hopper interpreted the `& 0xff` as a hint towards an unsigned variable in this case):

```
int _f1_u32(int arg0) {
    var_4 = arg0;
    if (var_4 != 0x0) {
            var_8 = (_f1_u32(var_4 >> 0x1) & 0xff) + 0x1;
    } else {
            var_8 = 0x0;
    }
    rax = var_8 & 0xff;
    return rax;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I was looking for an update to otx for legacy reasons, but for disassembling modern executables radare2 and Hopper seem to be better choices.  Thanks!